# Select First Observation with missings in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
ID  BP  Time value (sec)
1   75  10000
1   79  20000
2   81  30000
2   77  40000
2   83  50000
3   100 40000
3   104 30000
3   94  20000
3   101 50000
```

I want to select the first observation of BP for every ID. However, the column 'time value' is not in an ascending order for every id (e.g. ID =3). So, for every ID I want to select the value of BP for the lowest value of 'time value'. I've tried several things, for example creating a wide format but none of it worked out yet. Does anyone know an easy solution for this?

Thanks in advance!
Eveline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to do this. For each `ID`, the first (lowest `Time_value_sec` value) is grabbed using `rank` and filter.

```
library(dplyr)
# Given your data
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), BP = c(75L, 79L, 81L, 77L, 83L, 100L, 104L, 94L, 101L), Time_value_sec = c(10000L, 20000L, 30000L, 40000L, 50000L, 40000L, 30000L, 20000L, 50000L)), .Names = c("ID", "BP", "Time_value_sec"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

# Filtering: Grab the first item for each ID
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(rank(Time_value_sec, ties.method = "first") == 1)

# Output
## # A tibble: 3 x 3
## # Groups:   ID [3]
##      ID    BP Time_value_sec
##   <int> <int>          <int>
## 1     1    75          10000
## 2     2    81          30000
## 3     3    94          20000
```

**EDIT**

An alternate way is the following below. This assumes that the `Time_value_sec` column has unique values.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Time_value_sec == min(Time_value_sec))
```

Comment: If it works for you, can you accept the answer. You won't be able to up vote until you have 15 reputation.